# Getting urls one after another

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to call urls one AFTER another, not all at the same time, but no matter what I seem to try, they seem to all happen at the same time. This is what I have now...

```
$http.get('/some/url/foo1')
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo2'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo3'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo4'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo5'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo6'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo7'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo8'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo9'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo10'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo11'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo12'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo13'))
    .then($http.get('/some/url/foo14'));
```

These can't happen at the same time, when one completes, I want the next one to start.

EDIT: I've also tried putting the `get` in a function like this, but they still all get called at the same time

```
$http.get('/some/url/foo1')
    .then(rebuildModel('foo2'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo3'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo4'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo5'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo6'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo7'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo8'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo9'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo10'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo11'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo12'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo13'))
    .then(rebuildModel('foo14'));

    function rebuildModel(modelName) {
        return $http.get('/some/url/' + modelName);
    }
```

Edit2: This worked...I see what I did wrong

```
function rebuildModel(modelName) {
    return function () {
        return $http.get('/some/url/' + modelName);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your example, you are still "calling" the function instead of providing the definition of a function.  To fix your example try: function rebuildModel(modelName) { return function() {  return $http.get('url' + modelName); } };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining that you have done is incorrect. It should be something like this:

```
$http.get('/some/url/foo1')
    .then(function() { return $http.get('/some/url/foo2'); })
    .then(function() { return $http.get('/some/url/foo3');})
```

Remember the `then` function too returns a promise, that is resolved by the return value of its, success and error callbacks.

Comment: Tried that as well, see my update, but it didn't work.

Comment: @CaffGeek, this answer should work. If by "tried that" you meant your edit, then the difference is that in this case the anonymous function is passed to `.then`, whereas in your case, the `rebuildModel` function is invoked and the return value (a promise) is passed

Comment: Yep, changed the function one more time, and it seems to have worked. Thanks, I knew I needed to pass a function, not call one, but for some reason I just couldn't seem to write it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `then` method expects a success callback function as its first parameter:

```
$http.get('url').then(successCallback);
```

The `successCallback` must be a function definition, such as:

```
$http.get('url').then(function() { ... });
```

If you provide `$http.get()` as an argument:

```
$http.get('url').then($http.get('url'));
```

You are calling a function, and then passing the return value (which is a promise object) to the `then` method as the successCallback.

The situation is analogous to the following more obvious scenario:

```
a.  alert
b.  alert()
```

The first is a function definition, the second is calling the function.

I agree with Chandermani's answer, and it should be correct. If it is not working, perhaps check for errors:

```
$http.get('/some/url/foo1')
  .then(function() { return $http.get('/some/url/foo2'); })
  .then(function() { return $http.get('/some/url/foo3');},
   function() { alert('something went wrong');});
```